# How to count unique opens in a period of time in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: sql, dataview, soql, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I'm currently using Salesforce Data Views to retrieve how many times a user opened an email in the last 60 days. For now, I'm getting data from every time user opened, but I want to identify unique opens. My currently code is this one:

```
SELECT COUNT(SubscriberKey) as Count_Opens, SubscriberKey as email
FROM ENT._Open o
WHERE JobID IN (SELECT JobID FROM _Sent s WHERE EventDate > dateadd(d,-60,getdate()))
GROUP BY SubscriberKey
```

For example, my results are showing that my email address is associated with 104 opens. But I want to show only my unique opens, which is 33 in the last 60 days.

I am not identifying where can I make a change to retrieve just the unique event. Can I limit to no more than just one Open Event associated to a JobID and SubscriberKey? If I can, any suggestions on how to do it?

PS: sorry for my english.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Added which result I'm getting and which one I need. Thank you!

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) and [query](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query) tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `isUnique` flag.  It's described here in the [**_Open Data View documentation**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_open.htm&type=5).

```sql
SELECT 
  o.SubscriberKey as email
, COUNT(*) as Count_Opens
FROM _Open o
WHERE o.JobID IN (
    SELECT distinct
    s.JobID 
    FROM _Sent s 
    WHERE s.EventDate > convert(date, getDate()-60)
)
and o.isunique = 1
GROUP BY o.SubscriberKey
```

Also, Opens are scoped to business units, so the `ent.` prefix shouldn't apply in your case.

Comment: Thank you! It's retrieving the correct count now. I tried with IsUnique but not in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use isunique

You can use the below code

```
SELECT 
o.SubscriberKey as SubscriberKey
, COUNT(*) as Count_Opens
FROM _Open o
WHERE o.JobID IN (
    SELECT distinct
    s.JobID 
    FROM _Sent s 
    WHERE s.EventDate > convert(date, getDate()-60)
)
and o.isunique = 1
GROUP BY o.SubscriberKey
```